# Decorating a class whose constructor has arguments

Tags: python, python-decorators

How do I decorate a class whose constructor has arguments? This is my code;

```
# Base Class
class Model(object):
    models = {}
    def __init__(self):
        pass

# decorator
def register(cls):
    Model.models[cls.__name__] = cls()

#Subclasses

@register
class PaperModel(Model):
    def __init__(self, paper):
        self.paper = paper

@register
class WoodenModel(Model):
    def __init__(self, wood):
        self.wood = wood
```

The idea is to register instances of the subclass in the dict inside the base class.

When I run the code I get the following error

```
    Model.models[cls.__name__] = cls()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

However, if I remove the arguments in the subclass (PaperModel & WoodenModel) constructors the code works.

Comment: As per you, what do you think `Model.models[cls.__name__] = cls()` line does?

Comment: By instance, do you mean you want to save the object of class or the class itself?

Comment: @anonymous, object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `instance` i.e. object of the class (not the class itself) to be registered in the base class. Cleaner way would be to register the instances in the `__init__` of parent class, as the sub classes are derived from it. There is no point in creating the specific *decorator* for this. Decorators are for generic use, for example if Parent class was also dynamic. Your decorator should be registering things like: `<SomeClass>.models[<some_sub_class>]`

Below is the sample code for registering in the parent `__init__`:

```
# update the entry the __init__() of parent class
class Model(object):
    models = {}
    def __init__(self):
        Model.models[self.__class__.__name__] = self # register instance

class WoodenModel(Model):
    def __init__(self, wood):
        self.wood = wood
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()  # Make a call to parent's init()

# Create a object
wooden_model_obj = WoodenModel(123)

print wooden_model_obj
# prints: <__main__.WoodenModel object at 0x104b3e990>
#                                            ^

print Model.models
# prints: {'WoodenModel': <__main__.WoodenModel object at 0x104b3e990>}
#                                                            ^

# Both referencing same object
```

---

In case you want a generic decorator to achieve this, assuming:

- the child class has only one parent
- the attribute storing the value is as `models` in perent class

The sample decorator will be as:

```
def register(cls):
    def register_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        obj = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        obj.__class__.__bases__[0].models[cls.__name__] = obj
        # "obj.__class__.__bases__[0]" will return first inherited parent class
        return obj
    return register_wrapper
```

Comment: Thanks guys it worked, @Moses Kaledoye was on point, but l'll reward anonymous for demonstrating an alternative technique of registering subclasses inside the parent class. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to register the *instances* of annotated subclasses, the annotation must return something that will create the instances and register them.

By the way, if you use a simple dictionary, you will only register the last created instance of each subclass. If you want to register all instances, you should better use a `defaultdict(list)`

Here is an example of code:

```
class Model(object):
    models = collections.defaultdict(list)


def register(cls):
    def registrar(*args, **kwargs):
        # first create the instance with the passed parameters
        instance = cls(*args, **kwargs) 
        # then register the instance and return it
        Model.models[cls.__name__].append(instance)
        return instance
    return registrar

@register
class PaperModel(Model):
    def __init__(self, paper):
        self.paper = paper
```

This code can register different instances:

```
>>> p1 = PaperModel('A4')
>>> p1
<__main__.PaperModel object at 0x02AA0FB0>
>>> p2 = PaperModel('A3')
>>> p2
<__main__.PaperModel object at 0x02AA0F10>
>>> Model.models
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'PaperModel': [<__main__.PaperModel object at 0x02AA0FB0>, <__main__.PaperModel object at 0x02AA0F10>]})
```

---

Alternatively, you could not use an annotation at all, and use the special `__new__` method of the base class to obtain same result:

```
class Model(object):
    models = collections.defaultdict(list)
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        inst = super(Model, cls).__new__(cls)
        inst.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Model.models[cls.__name__].append(inst)
        return inst


class PaperModel(Model):
    def __init__(self, paper):
        self.paper = paper
```

This code is able to register instance too:

```
>>> p1 = PaperModel('A4')
>>> p2 = PaperModel('A3')
>>> Model.models
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'PaperModel': [<__main__.PaperModel object at 0x02AA02D0>, <__main__.PaperModel object at 0x02AA03F0>]})
>>> Model.models['PaperModel'][0] is p1
True
>>> Model.models['PaperModel'][1] is p2
True
```

Comment: I didn't actually think of class name collision when writing my answer. Good one.

Comment: You're solution using `__new__` doesn't account for the `paper` argument being passed to `object.__new__`, which raises a `TypeError`.

Comment: @Dunes: I only tested it on Python 2 but you are right, it choked on Python3. Fixed. Thanks for the remark...

Answer (score 3):

You should register the instance only when it's instantiated not before:

```
def register(cls):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        Model.models[cls.__name__] = inst
        return inst
    return wrapper
```

Note that you also need to return the class from the decorator else your decorator'll return `None` you'll get a `TypeError` when trying to use the decorator on the class.

---

```
wm = WoodenModel('log')
print(wm)
# <__main__.WoodenModel object at 0x033A6730>
print(Model.models)
# {'WoodenModel': <__main__.WoodenModel object at 0x033A6730>}
```

Comment: With your suggestion am getting the same error; inst = cls(*args, **kwargs) TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: You're not doing something right. Be sure you're running the updated code.

Comment: sorry my mistakes, disregard he comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can register the type rather than an instance (which you don't know how to construct, you don't have the right arguments available):

```
Model.models[cls.__name__] = cls # note no parens
```

Comment: I want to register the instance when I instantiate the subclass;